# Start app after boot using broadcast receiver not working in android 10

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-10.0, reboot

It working in android 9 devices after turn on autostart option for my app but for android 10 there is no option like auto start

Comment: make sure that you added the permission in manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>

Comment: @MuhammadAsad thx for your response, I am already trying an accessibility service that's not working and I have BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission in my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Wake lock is used when you start the service again after the device has been rebooted or when the service is killed.

Use it like this:

1. Create BroadcastReceiver for receiving the broadcast to start a service.

   ```
   public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
     LocalReceiver localReceiver = new LocalReceiver();
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
                context.startForegroundService(intent2);
            else
                context.startService(intent2);
           localReceiver.startMainService(context); //It will create a receiver to receive the broadcast & start your service in it's `onReceive()`.
         }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Register that receiver in the Manifest with `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` intent-filter.

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.demo.service.service_manager.AutoStart">
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. Now we have created the receiver which will receive a broadcast only one time when the device is rebooted. So we have to use wakelock manager to keep the register our service within a limited time.
4. Now, create the broadcast receiver which will be used to receive the broadcast to start the service.

   ```
   public class LocalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).wakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, ":YourService");
       wakeLock.acquire(60 * 1L); //It will keep the device awake & register the service within 1 minute time duration.
       context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, YourService.class), 1, 1);

       playMusic(); //Play your audio here.

       wakeLock.release(); //Don't forget to add this line when using the wakelock
   }
   ```

Now create a method in LocalReceiver to send the broadcast to start the service.

```
public void startMainService(Context context) {
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(context, LocalReceiver.class), 0);
}
```

That's it! We've successfully implemented the wake lock. Now, whenever you want to play a sound. Just send the broadcast to the LocalReceiver & it will get your job done.

Also, don't forget to register this receiver in the Manifest as well as add `android:enabled="true"` and `android:exported="true"` where you register your service in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name="com.demo.service.service_manager.LocalReceiver">
```

NOTE : We have used `playMusic()` inside the `onReceive()`. So it will also play the audio when the device is rebooted & the service will be registered. If you just want to bind the service on reboot, then you can simply add `startService()` method inside the `onReceive()` instead of the `playMusic()`.

Comment: You are a life saver man i have been searching for day's maybe month and this is the only answer that work

Comment: I wish you the best

Comment: @Farhoud I am glad it solved your problem. Keep spreading happiness & your knowledge :)

Comment: I want to launch my app on reboot, i am receiving the reboot in broadcast but start activity not working

Comment: pls, where is YourService.class?? can you pls provide the code for that?

Comment: @Zionnite That means your service class, e.g. MyService or whatever name you gave to your service class.